# ODE- stability of a fixed point $\dot x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

ODE- stability of a fixed point $\dot x=0$. The the fixed solutions are all vectors of $\Bbb{R}^n$, such that $x(t)=v,\Bbb{R}^n$. How can I tell it is stable? Can I say that for all $\epsilon>0$, all solutions with the starting condition $u\in B(v,\epsilon)$, are actually $x=u$ by the Uniqueness Theorem, which means that $r=\epsilon$ is the radius desired? (The one whose existence is required to make sure $v$ is stable.)

If I am completely wrong about this, what should I try, then?

Comment: As it was correcly noted in answers, you should clarify what notion of stability are you interested in: Lyapunov stability (when trajectories stay close to the specified trajectory, but not necessarily tend to it) or asymptotic Lyapunov stability. So, if you want to call this system Lyapunov stable, you are absolutely right and your analysis is absolutely right too. By obvious reasons, it's wrong to call any of equilibria of this system "asymptotic Lyapunov stable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more specific about the stability notion. Is that if each solution starting close to the fix point converges to this fix point (asymptotic stability) or just stay close to the fix point: for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x(t_0)-v|<\delta$ then $|x(t)-v|<\epsilon$ for all $t$.

Denote $\dot{x}$ to be $dx/dt$. First example is $\dot{x}=-x, \dot{y}=-y$, with $(0,0)$ asymptotically stable, the second is $\dot{x}=y,\dot{y}=-x$ with solutions staying on concentric circles (such a point is called a center).

In the case when ODE is of the form $\dot{x}=f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ (the system is autonomic i.e. the right hand side does not depend explicitly on time, which can be achieved by adding a time coordinate $T$ with $\dot{T}=1$)
one can investigate the  the derivative $df/dx$ at the fix point v. If the real parts of all the eigenvalues are negative the fix point is (hyperbolic) asymptotically stable (in the future for large positive time), it at least one is positive it is unstable (in the future some points escape a small neighborhood). The case of zero is tricky and the first order approximation does not answer the stability question. 
Try adding and subtracting quadratic terms in the center case.

See: stability of dynamical systems, Hartman-Grobman theorem, qualitative theory of ODE.

Answer (score 1):

No: points near the fixed point are typically not *themselves* fixed points. The most basic treatment, in the case of the autonomous equation $x'=f(x)$ with differentiable $f$, is to linearize the equation near the fixed point. This amounts to approximating it by the system $(x-x_0)'=A(x-x_0)$, where $x_0$ is the fixed point and $A$ is the Jacobian of $f$ at $x_0$.

When all eigenvalues of the linearization matrix $A$ have negative real part, the fixed point of the original system is asymptotically stable. When any eigenvalues of the linearization have positive real part, the fixed point of the original system is unstable. The situation when all eigenvalues have nonpositive real part and at least one has zero real part is subtle and requires different treatments in different problems.

Comment: Thank you for that, it really helps me get ahead. I guess what I am confused about is not being able to find the general solution, or the matrix. What kind of matrix can one use here?

Comment: @Meitar The matrix is the Jacobian of $f$ at $x_0$; its $(i,j)$ entry is $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x_0)$.